# Recipes executing out of order

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm on RedHat 6.5, and I want to use the mysql55 package from the IUS repo rather than the 5.1 package from base. In my attributes I have:

```
override['mysql']['server']['packages'] = %w{mysql55-server}
override['mysql']['client']['packages'] = %w{mysql55}
```

And the first two lines of my recipe are:

```
include_recipe 'yum::ius'
include_recipe 'mysql::server'
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
Chef::Exceptions::Package: No version specified, and no candidate version available for mysql55
```

Because it seems to be running the `mysql::server` recipe *before* `yum::ius` which would enable the IUS repo and make the mysql55 package available.

Everything I've found seems to indicate that Chef should be running these recipes in the order that they are specified, and I can't figure out why they're not. If it makes a difference, I've been tinkering with this cookbook and changing things around, so maybe there's a cache or something I should clear?

Comment: Can you post the output of the CCR with --log-level debug please?

Comment: Memory is a bit fuzzy, but this had something to do with a part of the MySQL recipe specifying *immediate* action rather than deferred. I ended up just going with the MySQL packages from base.